# Activity A is not moving to Activity B

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I have created App , which is working fine on some dices and there's a problem on some devices .

What I am trying to do is , I go to the Registration Activity from login activity by clicking on sign up button . After filling form the form data will be verified with server data and if the response is successfull , It should move to next activity but instead of moving to next activity it disappears the activity and move back on login activity .

this is the code for moving activity to next screen .

```
                   if (result.equals("true")) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationForm.this, 
                                                                RegistrationSubmitScreen.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                        finish();
                        Toast toasty = Toasty.success(RegistrationForm.this, "Data verified 
                                                         successfully .", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toasty.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toasty.show();
            }
```

The problem is , App is working fine on some device and show's the problem on some device .

Build.gradle(module) :

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
           compileSdkVersion 29
            buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.verge.safcoclient"
         minSdkVersion 19
         targetSdkVersion 29
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"

          testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

 buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
    }
  }
   dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
     implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
     implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'  
}
```

I will share more if needed .

Can anybody help me with that . ?

Comment: show your log error

Comment: @droidbaza Failed to find info cn.teddymobile.free.anteater.den.provider . 

i don't  know what it is because i am not using any provider or something

Comment: @droidbaza showing me above error in log ,

Comment: Why are you calling finish() after startActivity()? The Activity will close anyway. Are you trying to get it off the activity backstack (because there are other ways)? And what is that toast supposed to do after finish()? Calling finish() is kind of like calling return. You should put it into the next activity.

Comment: @einUsername yes i am trying to take it off from back stack . I do not want to go back after data is verified . What are the other ways? and toast for to let user know that his data is verified .